# How to freeze part of an object when scaling in Sketchup?

Tags: scale, sketchup

I have an object that represents a board with a 1/2" tenon on the ends. If I scale the board by changing the length, the 1/2" tenon changes length. Is there a way to change the length of the board but keep the tenons always 1/2"? In other words, if the length changes, the middle part of the board changes length, but the tenons remain the same length.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: p]

I have Pro, so I can do a dynamic component if that would be the best approach, but I can't figure out how to freeze a certain part of the object. I thought of creating the object with three different objects sandwiched together and then in the DC adjust the length of the outer (wider) part of the board independent of the center of the sandwich (the tenon part). Then, if possible, hide some of the edges to make it look like a single object. But I'm hoping this is easier than that and I'm just not experienced enough to know it.

Comment: I would posit that you do not want to use a direct(ish) modeler like sketchup but rather a indirect modeler like Solidworks, Creo, NX, Fusion360... Instead. Mainly because you think in a indirect fashion and will save you hundreds of hours over the span of a year if you do this to any extent (when we compared this with students we found that indirect modelers saved about 5-10 hours of work every week. But given direct modelers on average used 12 hours the savings were significant) but yeah moving faces would work in direct modellers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look at these.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't SketcUP Pro, but programs that capable should allow you to pull 3 faces simultaneously to get the wanted length. It's not scaling, you move the surfaces:

[image]

The screenshot is from DesignSpark Mechanical (=freeware)

Comment: I hadn't thought of DesignSpark and will look at it. Thanks for the suggestion. I would be interested if anyone knows if I can move the faces (surfaces) of the end of the board in Sketchup Pro dynamics components when I change the length of the board, keeping the .5 inch tenon.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the shape in half. Use "scale" to mirror one half. Now use "Pull" tool to lengthen at square cut end for the required length. Use "Union" in Tools, Solid Tools to arrive at your piece of correct length with undistorted tenon at each end.